# Multer middlware in Node.js returns empty object in req.body and undefined in req.file

Tags: node.js, express, postman, multipartform-data, multer

The problem is when I use multer and send a request in Postman the req.body comes as an empty object and the req.file comes as undefined. I've unchecked the content-type header in postman.

And here's the code:

```
//Route
const storage = multer.diskStorage({
    destination: function (req, file, cb) {
        cb(null, '../uploads/');
    },
    filename: function (req, file, cb) {
        cb(null, new Date().toISOString() + file.originalname);
    }
});

const upload = multer({
    storage,
    limits: {fileSize: 1024 * 1024 * 10}
});

router.post('/test', upload.single('profilePicture'), authController.test);

//Controller

const test = (req, res) => {
    console.log(req.body)
    console.log(req.files)
    res.json({body:req.body, files:req.files})
}

//app.js

app.use(express.json({extended: true, limit: '30mb'}));
app.use(express.urlencoded({extended: true, limit: '30mb'}))
app.use(cookieParser());

app.use('/api/auth', authRoutes);
app.use('/api/product', productRoutes);
app.use('/api/profile', profileRoutes);
```

Edit: turnes out, the problem is in Postman. I made a request with axios from a React app and everything works. So the question is, why doesn't it work in Postman? Is it some Bug in software or is there some settings that we're supposed to change?

Comment: If you configure with `var upload = multer({ dest: 'uploads/' })` there are same results?

Comment: Yup same thing. The problem as it turned out is in Postman.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that Nodejs is by default uses Ansynchornus Javascript. You need to use the `async-await` approach and `try-catch-finally` methods over conventional JS programming.

So your controller would look like -

```
//Route
router.post('/test', async (req, res, next)=>
 {
    try{
         await upload.single('profilePicture')
         next()
    } catch(err){
    console.log(err)
    res.send('failed!')
    }, 

authController.test);
```

```
//Controller

const test = async (req, res) => {
   try{

       console.log(req.body)
       console.log(req.files)
       res.json({body:req.body, files:req.files})
    } catch(err){
    console.log(err);
    }

}
```

A late addition to the answer.
If you're trying to just access the uploaded image, then you should make use of the `buffer`.

```
var storage = multer.memoryStorage()
var upload = multer({ storage: storage })
```

Comment: Hey man, thanks for the reply, but it didn't work, same result:  
{}
undefined

Comment: can you try changing the param 'profilePicture' to a variable like req.file or something?
I had a similar issue trying to reference by a hardcoded string in the multer upload fn

Comment: Also, you have to ```module.exports.test = async()``` to make it available in your route. Iguess you would've done that

Comment: Tried everything, same result. The problem is within Postman

Comment: Did this method work after solving your error in postman.